# Posting JSON to URL using PHP curl

Tags: php, json, curl

I have the following JSON code:

{"username":"user1","password":"123456"}

That I need to pass to a url, lets say: http://api.mywebsite.com

I'm an extreme php newb, so I've been following a curl tutorial, but here is my current PHP code:

```
<?php

function get_web_page( $url )
{
    $options = array(
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,     // return web page
        CURLOPT_HEADER         => true,    // don't return headers
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,     // follow redirects
        CURLOPT_ENCODING       => "",       // handle compressed
        CURLOPT_USERAGENT      => "spider", // who am i
        CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER    => true,     // set referer on redirect
        CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 120,      // timeout on connect
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 120,      // timeout on response
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS      => 10,       // stop after 10 redirects
    );

    $ch      = curl_init( $url );
    curl_setopt_array( $ch, $options );
    $content = curl_exec( $ch );
    $err     = curl_errno( $ch );
    $errmsg  = curl_error( $ch );
    $header  = curl_getinfo( $ch );
    curl_close( $ch );

    $header['errno']   = $err;
    $header['errmsg']  = $errmsg;
    $header['content'] = $content;
    return $header;

}

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look into the CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS AND CURLOPT_POST options. These allow you to do a POST request and pass the data set into the CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS in the request.

Something in the lines of this:

```
$body = 'bar=1&foo=2&baz=3';
$c = curl_init ($url);
curl_setopt ($c, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt ($c, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $body);
curl_setopt ($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you want to use normal GET Params:

```
$jsonString ='{"username":"user1","password":"123456"}';
$params = json_decode($jsonString);

$getParams = '';
$first = true;
foreach ($params as $key => $param){
    if ($first){
        $getParams .= '?';
        $first = false;
    } else{
        $getParams .= '&';
    }

    $getParams .= $key .'=' .$param;
}

echo $getParams;
get_web_page($url . $getParams);
```